# I applied jquery resizbale to codemirror but if i drag and make it small then scroll bar does not come automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, codemirror, jquery-ui-resizable

Scroll Bar does not come automatically 
in codemirror
if i apply jquery resizable to codemirror
and  make it smaller

Answer (score 0):

CodeMirror handles some its layout through scripts. You have to call the [`refresh`](http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#refresh) method after resizing the editor, to allow it to update itself.